# How To Change Functionality of escape key using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How To Assign Different Functionality To Escape Key  or How To Disable Escape Key On Browser Full Screen Mode Using Javascript/Jquery.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
    if (e.which == 27){
         // your code
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27){
        //do something
   }
});
```